# View is called before action is completed

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, nsurlconnection

I have a button used to download data and create a local db. Than, I want to open a table view with that data. It work but It seems the table view is called BEFORE the db cratio/actualization is made.

The code for the button is:

```
-(IBAction)downloadButton:(id)sender{

    [controller dowloadingFunction];  //contains soem function based on NS

    //the navigation controller to call the tableview
    ViewController *tableController =[[ViewController alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:tableController animated:NO];
}
```

the dowloadingFunction basically does:

```
{
...
   // perform the reqeust
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *myError = nil;

    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection
                    sendSynchronousRequest: request
                    returningResponse: &response
                    error: &myError];

    NSURLConnection *connectionPlatos = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [connectionPlatos start];
}
```

when conection receive data I call "parseJson" function to parse and create data base.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)d {

    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:d encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    //    NSLog(@"connection didReceiveData: %@",string);
    jsonPlatos = string;

    [self parseJson:jsonPlatos];      //<---- Funcion  to parse and create data base.

}
```

My question is about how make that the creation of data base ends BEFORE navigation controller is called. Any help , please?

Comment: Is there a reason you are requesting the data twice?  Your first request is the `NSData *data = [NSURLConnection syndSynchronousRequest: request: returningResponse &response error: &myError];` which is synchronous. Then you call `[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];` which is asynchronous. You would be best just removing the `NSURLConnection` if you are okay with a synchronous execution, and move your `parseJson:` method to after your `sendSynchronousRequest:` call.

Comment: glad that worked for you.